# How to check connectivity between opensuse vm client and server and how to remotely log in

Tags: ssh, opensuse, virtual-machine

I am new to openSUSE, I created an openSUSE VM acting as the server(Server_VM) where I enabled secure shell server and created a user account client_01 that is going to be used to access Server_VM remotely. sshd is installed on this server. Also, I created another openSUSE VM (Client_VM) that is going to be used as the client.

1. How do I ensure that Client_VM can connect to Server_VM using ping
   command? I just ping the the server name (Server_VM) from Client_VM 
   Console but it says unknown host Server_VM
2. How do I remotely login via SSH using the newly created account
   client_01?

Comment: which virtualization software do you use? is the networking correctly working between these two VMs? eg. perform `ifconfig` on server and try to `ping <server_ip>` from client

Comment: I used workstation 11.0 virtual machine

Comment: @lese I used workstation 11.0 virtual machine. The result of ifconfig on the server partly is as follows:  br0 Link encap: Ethernet HWaddr 00:0c:29:BC:3C:85, inet addr 192:168:5.132 Bcast:192.168.5.255 Mask: 255.255.255.0. so I pinged 192.168.5.132 from the client and the result I got was 316 packets transmitted, 316 received, 0% packet loss etc. I guess that means there is a connection between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. perform `ifconfig` on server and try to `ping <server_ip>` from
   client
2. You can login via `ssh` using the following command from
   **Client_VM**

   ```
   ssh client_01@192.168.5.132
   ```

   If you would connect using a "name", you could edit the `/etc/hosts`
   file on `Client_VM`, adding a line like this

   ```
   192.168.5.132   server-vm
   ```

   backup the file before edit it, just in case. From now on the
   **Client_VM** will know how to resolve the `server-vm` name, then you could establish `ssh` connection as follow

   ```
   ssh client_01@server-vm
   ```

   otherwise ( without `/etc/hosts` ) I think you will need to rely on
   a DNS server